# openpyxl set an alternative name for column in order to select easily

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is it possible to set an alternative name for column in openpyxl (especially, automatically set its headers as alternative names)? For example as below: give the alternative names

```
['my1', 'my2', 'my3']
```

to columns `A`, `B`, `C`. Then we can select column either by `ws['A']` or  `ws['my1']`.

[image]

The goal is to focus on the columns no matter how many columns I insert.

Comment: Just write your own mapping of column heading to column index.

Comment: @CharlieClark but when I insert a new column between B and C, then the mapping is not correct

Comment: Then update your mapping.

Comment: +1 on remarks from Charlie Clark. How could we know that your headers are in line 1? Also, what you are using is actually a Table (which formats data better in Excel). And you might consider using `pandas`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/02_read_write.html

Comment: maybe you can ignore headers. In pandas, everything is nature. But my problem is that how to do such thing in editor  excel. The reason I asked this question is that I remember some libraries of excel editor has such function and I want to confirm that if openpyxl has such function.